# Javascript get data from promise (axios)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, vuejs2, axios

I am making a Vue.js web-app and I am running into some javascript issues. I will describe the entire Vue.js setup just in case, but I don't think its really relevant. I know that there are other postss on this issue, but after a day and a half of trying to figure it out I couldn't find any posts that helped me enough to figure it out.

**The problem**:

I am trying to access data from my backend in my frontend. I am using an axios request that looks as follows:

```
axios.request({...}).then(function (response) { ... }.catch(function (error) { ... });
```

The `response` in the `.then` gets the correct data I want (an array) but I can't figure out how to get that data out, since the .then is a promise. The reason I need to get it out is because this is all inside a in a method inside a component and I want to equate the response to a value in my data variable. So basically I want to do:
`this.myvar = this.myvar.concat(response)`
but inside the `.then` I am outside of the scope of my component, so I want to get the response out of the `.then` so that I can change my data to it.

I understand that theoretically I can append more `.then`s to do what I want with the response, and that is how javascript handles the synchronicity, but there is nothing I want to do with the data, other than make an out-of-scope variable equal to it.

**My attempt:**

One thing I found is that I can declare a separate variable right before the axios request, and for some reason that variable will be available to me inside the `.then`. So I tried initializing a new variable to be a pointer to the component data variable that would be out-of-scope (`this.myvar`) and then change that variable in the `.then` to the response, but then that reaises other issues because I end up returning my function (that contains the axios request and everything) before that variable gets changed inside the `.then` do to the synchronicity and that causes other issues.

Edit: 
**My code**
this is a computed method inside a component. It has to return this.myvar as it is called inside a Vuejs template.

```
MyFunc: function () {  
    var a = this.myvar;                                                                                            
    axios.request({                                                                                                
        method: 'post',                                                                                              
        url: 'http://myURL:MyPort/query',                                           
        data: {                                                                                                      
           'mydata': dataToSend                                                                                                         
        },                                                                                                           
    }).then(function (response) {                                                                                  
        a = a.concat(Object.values(response.data.results));                                                        
    }).catch(function (error) {                                                                                           
        console.log(error);                                                                                          
    });
    return this.myvar
}
```

This is not the first time I have had problems with promises in javascript, I have tried reading up on them but I just can't understand completely how to deal with them. Any help would be grteatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is within a Vue component, then you need to understand some concepts:

a) A computed property can not be asynchronous. It needs to return a value right away, from values already available

b) You can request asynchronous values using axios, and when you get the response, you just assign the value into a property in the component data

```
data: () => {
    return {
        dataFromServer: undefined,
    };
},
methods: {
    getDataFromServer() {
        axios.get(url)
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then(data => {
                this.dataFromServer = data;
            })
    },
},
```

c) Finally, if you need a computed property from a value that comes from the server, you define it like this:

```
computed: {
    derivedValue() {
        return this.dataFromServer? this.dataFromServer * 2 : undefined;
    },
}
```

Initially, `derivedValue` will be undefined, as it depends on a value that is not yet available. However, as soon as the value returns from server and you assign it to `this.dataFromServer`, Vue.js will work it's magic, and will automatically recalculate `derivedValue`, updating every place where it appears.

It is important to realize that in your template you can use either `dataFromServer` or `derivedValue`. And also, take into account that for a short time, those values will be undefined, until the server response gets back to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I approved the answer. Out of curiousity, why did you have the `*2` there? I didn't use it and it was fine

Comment: It was just a silly example of derived value: the original value multiplied by 2. If you don't need to modify the original value, then in your template you can use `dataFromServer` directly

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special;  You can return the data from the `.then` block as follows:

```
axios.request({...})
.then(function (response) { 
  return response.data;  // Or assign it to a variable or state in your app
}
.catch(function (error) { 
  ...
});
```

jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/rj4pgwek/

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! that looks exactly like what I want to do, and its was my first attempt, but then I got `"this is not defined"` so I assumed that because .then declared a function then the scope of my component wasn't kept. Any idea why I would be getting that error?

Comment: In your case likely `this` is out of lexical scope... It's hard for me to help you if there is no code context.  You would need to post your full code for me to give a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using async and await to make async function so the function may look like this without the need of

```
.then

const myAsyncFunc = async () => {
    const axiosURI = 'Some_URI_To_call'
    const res = await axios.post(axiosURI, {
      params:{}
    });
}
```

the result will be in the **res** variable so you can use it to get clone to **res** into another variable to be reusable in some place else

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried using await before, but not exactly like this, I'll give it a try, and see if it works!

Comment: using arrow function will prevent unexpected behavior because it recognizes **this** from the nearest scope of it , but in case you have reserved scope to the calling instance you can pass **this** as parameter to your function .